# Buscar la menor lista de un grupo de sublistas si el primer lugar es común

Tags: python

llevo varios días buscando la solución.
Tengo  esta lista de listas.

```
lista = [[10, -400, 410], [10, -200, 210], [10, 100, 90], [-65, -400, 335], 
[-65, -200, 135], [-65, 100, 165], [-30, -400, 370], [-30, -200, 170], [-30, 100, 130]]
```

debo buscar la menor lista  según su ultimo índice pero siempre y cuando el primer índice  sea igual.
debería quedar  así: `lista = [ [10, 100, 90], [-65, -200, 135], [-30, 100, 130]]`

```
minimos=lista[0][-1]
for i in range(0, len(lista)-1,1):
    if lista[i][0]==lista[i+1][0] and lista[i][-1]<=minimos:
        minimos=lista[i][0]
    minimos.append(minimos)
print(minimos)
```

Comment: En el ejemplo que das el primer índice no es igual al último, podrías expresar mejor lo que quieres?

Comment: @Christian, se refiere al primer índice de todos

Comment: se debe buscar la menor  de las listas simpre que  su primer índice sea igual, es decir de las listas que empiezan  con 10, la menor. las que empiezan con -65 la menor, las que empiezan con -30, la menor. Gracias.

Comment: @JeanGotopo haaa.. ya entendí, gracias 

Comment: La variable minimos te esta dando un entero (int) por lo que no puedes usar append con esta variable

Comment: pero += suma el dato

Comment: Dónde tienes el +=? Aun cuando sumaras minimos con su valor anterior sigue dando entero, no puedes usar método append con enteros, debes crear una lista aparte para in agregando los valores

Comment: si en lugar de append usamos minimos+=minimos

Comment: Igual te daría un entero, específicamente te daría -1040

Comment: mas o menos así?

Comment: minimos=lista[0][-1]
lista_minimos=[]
for i in range(0, len(lista)-1,1):
 if lista[i][0]==lista[i+1][0] and lista[i][-1]<=minimos:
  minimos=lista[i][0]
 lista_minimos.append([minimos])
print(minimos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo, quieres esto:

```
lista = [
    [10, -400, 410], [10, -200, 210], [10, 100, 90], # [10, 100, 90]
    [-65, -400, 335], [-65, -200, 135], [-65, 100, 165], # [-65, -200, 135]
    [-30, -400, 370], [-30, -200, 170], [-30, 100, 130] # [-30, 100, 130]
]
```

Se me ocurre acumular en un diccionario donde el `key` corresponde a los indices `[0]` y el `valor` a una lista correspondiente a `lista[0]` = `key`. En el `for` se irá comparando cada sublista con su correspondiente key, si el valor[2] es menor que el acumulado en el diccionario, se reemplaza por esta otra lista.

La ventaja de este método es que las sublistas pueden estar en cualquier orden y pueden tener cantidad variable de cada tipo.

```
d = {}
for elem in lista:
    idx = elem[0]
    if idx not in d or (elem[2] < d[idx][2]):
        d[idx] = elem
```

Hasta este punto el diccionario `d` tendrá este sub-resultado:

```
{10: [10, 100, 90], -65: [-65, -200, 135], -30: [-30, 100, 130]}
```

Para obtener solo la lista de resultados:

```
resultado = [v for k,v in d.items()]
# [[10, 100, 90], [-65, -200, 135], [-30, 100, 130]]
```

Comment: Es General. Mil Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puede hacer con una comprensión de lista, donde itere sobre la lista, como me di cuenta que hay 3 valores seguidos traté de simplificar la búsqueda escogiendo solo algunos valores de la lista con la notación `slice`

```py
minimos = [min(lista[lista.index(i):lista.index(i)+3], key=lambda x: x[-1]) for i in lista[::3]]

print(minimos)
```

Aquí la variable i representará cada posición de los electos de la lista cogidos de 3 en 3. Luego obtenemos los índices de los elementos para poder obtener los otros siguientes, luego usamos la función `min()` para obtener el mínimo y usamos la lambda para indicarle que saque el mínimo de acuerdo al último elemento

**resultado**

```
[[10, 100, 90], [-65, -200, 135], [-30, 100, 130]]
```

Comment: Gracias, llevo 8 días con este problema.... bueno 1.5 meses con Python. Ya alcanzare  este nivel. Gracias. Aunque no siempre es 3 si ves  el ultimo campo corresponde al valor absoluto de la resta de los  2 primeros, esta lista es el resultado de  otras 2. Luego debo  construir un diccionario  con las listas  que resulten cuya clave  sea  el segundo valor. Mil gracias

Comment: Jefe de nada, puedes quitarnel sílice pero obtendrás resultados repetidos, esto lo hago para minimizar las interacciones en la lista